# Why does Homer say The Who used to be named The Hillbilly Bugger Boys?

Tags: the-simpsons

In *The Simpsons* epsiode "A Tale of Two Springfields" (S12E02), Homer says about The Who:

> It's not fair! I've been a fan of The Who since the very beginning, when they were The Hillbilly Bugger Boys.

Why does he say that? Is it a completely made up, non-sense name? Or is this some sort of pop cultural reference I'm not aware of?

Comment: There might be a pop culture reference here but note that often Simpsons phrases are just nonsensical in the first place.

Comment: Hm, the who are british. afaik Hillbilly is a typically american term. So i would wonder if there is a real connection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The joke is in the incredulousness (and the inappropriateness) of a band called 'The Hillbilly Bugger Boys'.

Whilst 'Bugger' is British colloquial slang for 'damn', 'Buggery' is the act of anal sex, typically performed upon another male.

So, if someone were to say (translated) "I'm a fan of 'the Trailerpark Gayboys", the shock reaction on hearing their name would be:

### "The WHO?!"

Comment: That's the kind of explanation I was looking for! I didn't know the meaning of those terms. In latin american spanish it was dubbed as "Los Campesinos de Sodoma" which could be translated as "The Sodom's Farmers"

Comment: Astounding!  .......